# How to populate a mongo object using "foreign keys" array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, denormalization, nosql

So I have a `Channel` model and a `Subscriber` model.

A channel has an attribute which holds an array of IDs corresponding to subscribers which have signed up.

I've been sitting here cracking my skull against the wall with `async`:

1. Get a list of channels, then at the end of that callback
2. Get a list of subscriber IDs from that channel, then at the end of that callback
3. Using `async` again, for every subscriber ID, run a mongoDB query to snag the user profile and amend the initial list of channels

This seems horribly wrong. Should the `Subscriber`s LIVE inside the Channels as embedded documents? If that's the case, do I have to do a search inside all of the channels and all of their embedded documents, when, say, a user needs to login?

What if I want to maintain them separate - like I'd like to do with users, bidders, other entities that I don't feel should belong as embedded documents?

PS: I don't want to use Mongoose.

Is there an easier way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using mongo when you have this kind of relational data? mongo is not relational database by nature, it's designed to keep documents that are not in relation with each other, means each document record is self contained, but in your case you have this "foreign keys" which is against to what mongodb stands for.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, you could do an $in query. You have the array of subscriberIDs for a given channel, so you do an $in query on the subscribers/users collection.

```
db.subscribers.find({userID:{$in: IDsArray}})
```

But in general, with Mongo you will have to do these kind of joins manually through the app layer. You can also embed the subscribers into the channel docs, if you are not going to sue them elsewhere.
Or you can switch to a relational DB such as Postgres.

Hope this helps, it should eliminate having to loop through all the Subscriber IDs and doing a find on each.